# Responsive website and Print Stylesheet issue

Tags: html, css, printing

I have set a responsive style sheet for my website and here is part of the CSS file responsible to empty some space for the navigation-menu on the left :

```
@media (min-width: 48em) {
    #layout { padding-left: 150px }
}
```

I've also set a *print.css* file as dedicated print style sheet as follow where I set the menu to hide and it's space to be omitted :

```
@media print {
    #layout { padding-left:0 }
    #menu { display : none }
}
```

The problem is that, while in print preview, the menu will hide but there's still the 150px white space on the left side of the content, no matter what, I've even tried :

```
    #layout { padding-left:0 !important }
```

But no luck,

When I manually change the ***padding-left*** value to 0 using the Chrome's built-in feature (Inspect element), the page shows up alright in print preview, but the code in *print.css* does not seem to be applied no matter what.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the code you tried

Comment: Here is the live website : www.saberdriver.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right after a lot of testing. I got it figured out. It seems the **padding-left** problem is only happening in Google Chrome's print preview, since all the other browsers print-preview respect print CSS. So everything is fine with my CSS, and this is browser related bug.